# Making Modern Firearms In A Pre-Industrial Society - Cottage Industry

Tags: warfare, firearms, pre-industrial, manufacturing

What is the feasibility of producing (on a wide scale) modern firearms (particularly small arms) of the type found roughly in the First World War and Second World War (bolt action rifles, submachine guns, and machine guns)in a pre-industrial society where creation of such weapons and the ammunition thereof would be done in individual workshops?

Ignoring how the tools and knowledge came to be could say, a submachine gun, be built by craftsmen? Without industrialization how many say bolt action rifles could be produced and of what quality? Could ammunition be reliably made in adequate enough quantities with individual craftsmen workshops?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116819/discussion-on-question-by-cosmic-orrery-making-modern-firearms-in-a-pre-industri).

Answer (score 6):

There had been industrial production of firearms before the industrial revolution. 1500s Japan was by no means an industrialized country, but in all facts a medieval country torn apart by warlords. However, by 1600 this country managed to produce more than 300000 matchlock guns in less and sixty years. All those guns had been created in workshops. Some of them by individual Masters, others by what must appear as pre-industrial manufacturing complexes with apprentices doing nothing but boring, carving stocks or fitting parts. Before 1600! While not necessarily using interchangeable parts, the design of all these firearms is pretty much exactly the same! Guns made Japan adopt the Manufactory principle without much of a precursor there!

Rifle manufactories started to be a thing in Europe even before artisan manufactories became a thing in the early 1600s France: **Beretta in Venetia/Italy was created back in 1526** making arquebuses for the city-state on an industrial scale. **In fact, the (equally old) Venetian Arsenal churned out one new (or repaired) ship a day at peak performance.** That is with renaissance tooling and construction!

To make bolt action rifles, you only need to add somewhat modern tooling to the workshops of 1600s Venetian arsenals: You need decently powered and accurate lathes and mills to get to bolt action.

Decentralized manufacturing or rather **standardized manufacturing** of modern guns is **not** an option with pre-industrial machining or small workshops, as the ability to keep the tolerances among various shops simply isn't there! Why could muskets be mass manufactured? To shoot a musket, you put an under-caliber lead ball into a greased piece of cloth and ram that down the bore. The cloth acts as a sealant. Later rifled muskets do use soft lead bullets that get *engraved* with the rifling as they are pushed down the bore. The soft lead and the wadding are what allows them to get away with huge tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

### The chief characteristics of a WWII quality firearm are as follows:

- A barrel made within a tolerance of about 1:1000th of an inch.
- Riffling
- Cartridge ammo with a clip
- Automatic or Semi-automatic firing mechanism
- Percussion caps
- Muzzle velocities of 750-850 m/s

*For purposes of this answer I will assume that your cottage industry knows everything they need to know to make a modern firearm, and that you only want to know if it could be done with the tools available prior to the Industrial Revolution (1760) in workshops small enough to be owned by individuals.*

**Barrel Tolerance**

Prior to the inventions of the metal lathe, the best method for making gun barrels was the [damascus forging method](https://ethw.org/Barrel_Boring#The_Damascus_Barrel) where small scraps of steel where forge welded around a mandrel to create a roughly "bored" barrel.  Once the barrel was done, it was hand finished with a tool called a ream which would carve away any defects within a precision of ~0.0005"; so, barrels of WWII level precision were certainly doable with pre-industrial technology.  But, if you want weapons and ammo to be interchangeable between makers, you would need to standardize.  This is actually easier done than most people think. By the late 1500s, the British had already standardized their cannon industry such that a cannon made by any British workshop would fit the ammo made by any other workshop.  All this takes is someone having a single master template from which all state approved barrel reams and ammo are made.  Early calipers were just as precise as what manual options we have available today, but they could only be used for transferring measurements, not recording them because they had no gauges.  So, if you have a template used as the master for all of your production, you could use calipers to make copy-templates to send to all of your workshops.  These copy templates could be measured and crafted to within ~0.001" based on what I've seen prototype craftsmen do by hand with similar tools.   The copy-templates would then have to be used as a reference point for finishing the barrel which would introduce a 2nd ~0.001" varrience.  The precision of a hand ream  would then introduce another ~0.0005" varrience for a total variance of 0.0025".  Since a modern lead bullet is designed to compress as it enters the barrel, there is actually a fair allowance for variance because there is a range of "loose" vs "tight" fitting in which the lead will still shape to the barrel and fire.  0.0025" is more than tight enough of a variance to allow any lead bullet made to fire in it. This is not going to be quite as precise of a fit as many WWII sniper rifles, but at least as good as many submachine guns or assault rifles.

**Riffling**

Hand tooled riffling has been around since at least 1525. [Early rifle bores were cut using a hand wrought helix to guide a wooden rod ended with an engraving tool](https://ethw.org/Barrel_Boring#The_Damascus_Barrel).  While riffling was not very standardized, this is less important.  Lack of standardization may mean one bullet spins a little more or less than another, but by in large this will not affect the important characteristics of your firearm.

**Cartridge ammo with a clip**

Cartage ammo can be made entirely from hand tools and a rolling mill.  Rolling mills have been around since 600 BCE and [slitting mills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slitting_mill) have been around since 1590CE. It would only take a slight variation to a slitting mill to be able to make a machine that could form large numbers of precisely cut metal bullet casings in a single pass.

The harder part will be the clip. The big technical constraint on clips is the need for spring steel.  European sword smiths have been making some pretty high quality high quality spring steel since the medieval period; so, clips are doable, but without modern thermometers, they would take a master smith to get right.

**Automatic or Semi-automatic firing mechanism**

Gas operated reloading was not invented until 1856, but the design of a gas reloader is actually pretty simple. It's basically just a piston, spring, and catch.  All the parts could be hand crafted using a lot of the same methods I've already described previously  in this answer.

[image]

**Percussion Caps**

The fulminantes used to make percussion caps were not discovered until the early 1800s, but as I said at the start, we will assume that "your cottage industry knows everything they need to know to make a modern firearm" so the question is not if people knew about fulminantes before the industrial revolution, but if you needed the industrial revolution to happen to be able to invent fulminantes.  The [Mercury(II) fulminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury(II)_fulminate) used in percussion caps is made by dissolving [mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(element)#History) in [nitric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_acid#History) and adding [ethanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol#History) to the solution. Refining process for making all 3 of these ingredients have been around for over 1000 years; so, making percussion caps in a pre-industrial society is pretty easy as long as you know how.

**Muzzle velocities**

There are 2 big reasons for the increase in muzzle velocities during the industrial revolution, 1 is better steel, the other is better gunpowder.  The biggest difference between industrial era steel and medieval era steel is the addition of magnesium.  While the process for isolating magnesium in the modern era usually involves electrolysis, there are also [thermal reduction process](https://www.britannica.com/technology/magnesium-processing#ref82156) that were favored in China specifically because they are easier to do in cottage industry based economy.  There are a few variations, but in general, they involve heating dolomite and silicon together to release magnesium gas which is then distilled into an isolated metal.  Once you have magnesium, you can make modern gun-steel able to survive greater explosive forces than carbon steel.

As for modern gunpowder, what you are looking for is called [Cordite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordite) which is gun cotton treated with [nitroglycerine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitroglycerin).  Gun cotton is made from a solution of [nitric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_acid) and [sulfuric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid) used on plant fibers (both acids predate the industrial revolution).  Nitroglycerine is made from Glycerol (made by heating fats or oils mixed with a number of possible metal filings) and sulfuric acid (has been around since before industrial revolution).  So, the production chain for modern gunpowder is a bit complex, but all of the individual processes are very simple to do in your own home.  So, this totally works in a cottage industry setting.

### Conclussion

All the bits and pieces that go into a modern firearm industry are a bit too complex for 1 person to do in their own home, but that is not important.  A community of people working together, each doing specialized tasks within their own homes and personal workshops could absolutely make modern style firearms, and that is what a typical cottage industry actually is.

Comment: Not with the tollerances - you need to do some tasks in one and the same machine without removing the workpiece from the holder - that is what keeps the tollerances low. 1600s technology doesn't allow 1-thou tollerances.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question really depends of what level of knowledge these workshops have access to and what is meant by industrialization.

The basic answer is, with modern knowledge and access to the appropriate resources, crude but workable bolt action rifles could be produced by skilled workers equipped with 16th century era (I chose this time period because it is widely regarding as pre-industrial) tools, as could working metal cartridges to be used with the rifles. It would take a while, the end results would be crude and far lower quality than anything on the market today, and the finished product's look and function would be constrained by the circumstance and in all likelihood not be like the weaponry we are used to seeing. However, knowledge of material science and chemistry and access to right materials is the issue of being possible vs. impossible. The time constraint to build an exact replica of an Uzi would not be very feasible, however. For a discussion regarding recreating modern technology in both form and function from scratch, as opposed to reproducing modern technology in function only, see the informative idiocy that is Thomas Twaites: "The Toaster Project: Or A Heroic Attempt to Build a Simple Electric Appliance from Scratch" (2011)

Since the central question is industrialization, what exactly is meant needs to be addressed. If it is knowledge and application of electricity that is meant (steampunk for instance), then this is not strictly necessary, but is near impossible to explain knowledge of advanced metallurgy and chemistry without first understanding electricity. Industrialization, as a phenomena arising from converging social, economic and political circumstances which enables wide spread labor to shift from an agrarian to manufacturing basis as enabled through the transfer of knowledge and resources, is also not strictly necessary but also not limited to the 17-18th century. While global industrialization happened during this time frame, there are many instances of localized industrialization, including in the manufacture of weaponry which happened historically, for example, in Damascus or in Toledo. Without industrialization, knowledge and access to plentiful resources becomes problematic and need to be explained.

To elaborate, constructing metal cartridges (required for bolt-action rifles) requires making a bullet, a casing, having propellent and a primer. One of the primary reasons that metal cartridges weren't made until the middle of the 19th century was that a suitable primer material was not yet invented (the casing, bullets and propellent had all been around or were possible for some time). It was advances in the knowledge of chemistry which enabled the manufacture of primers, which were in turn enabled by the processes of electrolysis which requires knowledge of electrical currents.

Ultimately the answer rests in the knowledge of the workers and what they have access to. Suppose this village workshop in 16th century France was suddenly staffed by a rag-tag team of highly brilliant experts from 2020 and they wanted to build the bolt-action rifle; but only had 16th century tools. The first thing they'd probably do is go about to build more appropriate tools and machines, a lathe for example which hadn't yet been invented, before starting their project...